# Split taxonomy column base category,brand and designer

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

```
<?php
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

$object_id = $row2['object_id'];
$sql ="select term_taxonomy_id from wp_term_relationships where object_id =
$object_id";
$results = mysql_query($sql);

while($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($results)){

    $term_taxonomy_id1[] = $row3['term_taxonomy_id']."<br/>";

  }

}
print_r($term_taxonomy_id1);
?>
```

After used above code i fetched term_taxonomy_id in array

```
    Array (
    [0] => 249
    [1] => 250
    [2] => 251
    [3] => 252
    [4] => 250
    [5] => 251
    [6] => 254
    )
```

i want to fetch term_id (base on Split taxonomy column in category,brand and designer)

this is table structure

Table: wp_term_taxonomy

[image]

i need output like that

```
       Array
    (
    [category] => Array
      (
      [0] => 177
      [1] => 179
      )
    [brand] => Array
      (
      [0] => 176
      )
    [designer] => Array
      (
      [0] => 175
      [1] => 180
      )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

      $object_id = $row2['object_id'];

      $sql ="select term.term_taxonomy_id,wp.term_id from wp_term_relationships as term  inner join wp_term_taxonomy as wp ON term.term_taxonomy_id=wp.term_taxonomy_id where object_id = $object_id";

      $results = mysql_query($sql);

      $i=0;
     while($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($results)){
         $term_taxonomy_id1[$i] = $row3['term_taxonomy_id'];

         $res_term_id[$i] = $row3['term_id'];

       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I got this right since I don't understand the need for **term_taxonomy_id** but nevertheless if it could help you:

```
$data=array();
while($row3=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $taxonomy=$row3['taxonomy'];
  $sql2="select term_id from wp_term_relationships where taxonomy=$taxonomy";
  $res=mysql_query($sql2);
  while($row4=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
    $tab[]=$row4['term_id'];
  }
  $data[$taxonomy]=$tab;
}
```

It's not the best, you can still work with JOIN procedures to improve performance but it should work.